# The repository finds three records, and the resulting list returns 6 records

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

The repository finds three entries in the request sending controller, and 6 entries are placed in the list

Please help me why this happens, I do not understand ((((((

Domain class User generated unique ids:

```
public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;
```

Controller methods:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('_2_TEACHER')")
    @GetMapping("/project/{projectId}/party/create")
    public String viewTeacherCreateProjectParty(
            @PathVariable("projectId") Project project,
            Party party,
            Model model) {
        List<User> users = userService.userList(Sort.by("username"));
        model.addAttribute("project", project);
        model.addAttribute("party", party);
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "teacherProjectPartyCreate";
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('_2_TEACHER')")
    @PostMapping("/project/{projectId}/party/create")
    public String processCreateProjectParty(
            @PathVariable("projectId") Project project,
            @Valid Party party,
            @RequestParam(value = "users") List<Long> usersIds,
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model model) {
        List<User> users = userService.findUsersByUserIdIn(usersIds);
        model.addAttribute("project", project);
        model.addAttribute("party", party);
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        Long projectId = projectService.createProjectParty(project, party, users);
        return "redirect:/projects/project/" + projectId;
    }
```

Methods in service:

```
public List<User> userList(Sort sort) {
    return userRepo.findAll(sort);
}

public List<User> findUsersByUserIdIn(List<Long> usersIds) {
    return userRepo.findUsersByUserIdIn(usersIds);
}
```

Methods in repository:

```
List<User> findAll(Sort sort);

List<User> findUsersByUserIdIn(List<Long> usersIds);
```

Debug screed:

[image: ig]

Comment: what type of repository is it? did you try with @Query?

Comment: CrudRepository, No, I haven’t tried it yet with @Query, but it’s still not clear why this can be ((

Comment: It is very strange that when you call methods directly through the repository, the records are without duplicates. https://pastenow.ru/783f8e67123c4832b29e497b5d768b61

    List<User> findUsersByUserIdIn(List<Long> usersIds);

    List<User> findUserByUserIdIn(List<Long> userId);

Comment: These screenshots show that the results themselves in the repository are correct, but the list through the service returns a double list, why so? https://prnt.sc/s5da9i https://prnt.sc/s5db4d

Comment: not sure but you can check for user list in service and also check if you are injecting right bean for userservice in controller.

Comment: Two identical operations, but the first contains a double result ((((((((( https://prnt.sc/s5di5r

Comment: if everything is correct then spring does not have any such problem ... may be IDE have some problems.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I solved the problem by removing all browser extensions and restarting the project. I noticed that the controller methods were executed twice, but because of what - this is a mystery

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing all browser extensions and restarting the project. I noticed that the controller methods were executed twice, but because of what - this is a mystery